# diff between application transaction scope and sql server transaction

Tags: transactions

I want to know:

1. diff between application transaction scope and sql server transaction.
2. where to use application transaction
3. where to use sql server transaction

Answer (score 0):

A transaction is a combination of actions, that are either all done, or not done. This applies to both cases.

For instance, an SQL Server transaction can be multiple SQL statemnets, which are either all executed, or none are executed.

An application transaction may be multiple actions like: remove a button from the user interface, and add another button. Putting those two actions into an application transaction would ensure, that there is always one button present.

Application transaction may include the execution of database transactions.